# Slick Grid Multi select issue

Tags: slickgrid

I'm using `SlickGrid`. I can select multiple rows with pressing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button.

How I can achieve this without pressing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [handleClick](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/gh-pages/plugins/slick.rowselectionmodel.js) (*line 131*) function expects a "modifier" key to be pressed (*line 138*) when selecting more than one row. To overcome this expectation, you'll need to provide a custom `RowSelectionModel` implementation that removes the logical checks.

Another option would be to use the [CheckboxRowSelector](http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-checkbox-row-select.html) for multi-row selection.

Comment: Could you please explain how to provide RowSelectionModel implementation to remove the logical checks

Comment: I just pulled down the source for that plugin and modified the handleClick method by removing all of the `&& e.ctrlKey` statements.

Comment: I cant select rows using shift button

Comment: If you want shift selection you'll need to move the check for it above the index based checking as it will never execute due to the other two logical paths having precedence in all cases.

Comment: I'm trying to do integer column sorting in slick grid but its not working properly Could you please tell me how to do it. Here is my code for numeric sorting   function comparer(a, b) {           
       var x = (isNaN(a[sortcol]) || a[sortcol] === "" || a[sortcol] === null) ? -99e+10 : parseFloat(a[sortcol]);
       var y = (isNaN(b[sortcol]) || b[sortcol] === "" || b[sortcol] === null) ? -99e+10 : parseFloat(b[sortcol]);
       return   (x === y ? 0 : (x > y ? 1 : -1));
}

Comment: Since column sorting is not part of this question, it should be addressed in a new question.